# Objective c block will retain UI autorelease issue?

Tags: ios, user-interface, block, autorelease

I understand that Objective C will retain `localVariable`,

```
id localVariable = instanceVariable;

dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    // localVariable is used by value, localVariable is retained (not self)
    doSomethingWithObject(localVariable);
});
```

but this retain is happened just when block is triggered ?  if so, while the `localVariable` is an UI object such as `UIViewController` which maybe controlled by autorelease pool, if I just create an `UIViewController` managed by autorelease pool and not retain it or use it, while one event loop finished, it will be dealloced, then inside the block, I can't use this `UIViewController` anymore ? and I have to retain it manually outside block ?

Answer (score 1):

No, `localVariable` will be retained by the block when the block is created.